# ERROR Object Variable or block variable not set.... what exactly it mean

Tags: vba, macros, ribbon, excel-addins

I add my macro code to add in and n customize ribbon and now it showing error "Object variable or with block variable not set"... [image]

When i run my add in macro code for another 2nd time this error occurs 
[image]

**what kind Object variable should be set or declare any help ?**

***CODE :***
     Option Explicit

```
 Sub MakeWordList()
 Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult

  answer = MsgBox("ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO RUN THIS WORD COUNT MACRO...? ",       vbYesNo, "RUN WORD COUNT")
If answer = vbYes Then

Dim InputSheet As Worksheet
Dim WordListSheet As Worksheet
Dim Result As Worksheet
Dim PuncChars As Variant, x As Variant
Dim i As Long, r As Long, lastrow As Long
Dim txt As String
Dim wordCnt As Long
Dim AllWords As Range
Dim pc As PivotCache
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim OutClm As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set InputSheet = ActiveSheet
Set WordListSheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count))
WordListSheet.Activate
WordListSheet.Name = "temp"
WordListSheet.Range("A1:B1") = "All Words"
WordListSheet.Range("A1:B1").Font.Bold = True
InputSheet.Activate
wordCnt = 2
PuncChars = Array(".", ",", ";", ":", "'", "!", "#", "-", "--", "---", "@", "`", _
   "$", "%", "&", "(", ")", " - ", "_", "--", "+", "<", ">", "BLANK", _
    "=", "~", "/", "\", "{", "}", "[", "]", """", "?", "*", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
        r = 1

   OutClm = 1
 '   Loop until blank cell is encountered
     Do While Cells(r, 1) <> ""
 '       covert to UPPERCASE
         txt = UCase(Cells(r, 1))
  '       Remove punctuation
       For i = 0 To UBound(PuncChars)
              txt = Replace(txt, PuncChars(i), "")
        Next i
     '       Remove excess spaces
       txt = WorksheetFunction.Trim(txt)
   '       Extract the words
    x = Split(txt)

    For i = 0 To UBound(x)
        If wordCnt > WordListSheet.Rows.Count Then
             OutClm = OutClm + 1
             wordCnt = 1
         End If
            WordListSheet.Cells(wordCnt, OutClm) = x(i)
            wordCnt = wordCnt + 1
    Next i
r = r + 1
Loop
'
  ' Macro1 Macro
  WordListSheet.Activate

Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Copy
Columns("D:D").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("E1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "COUNT"
Range("D2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
Range("D3").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("E1048576").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Selection.FillDown
Range("E1048575").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Columns("D:E").Select
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "temp!R1C4:R1048576C5", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="temp!R1C7:R1C8", TableName:="PivotTable1", _
    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
Sheets("temp").Select
Cells(1, 7).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("All Words")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable1").PivotFields("COUNT"), "Sum of COUNT", xlSum
Columns("G:H").Select
Selection.Copy
Columns("J:K").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Columns("B:B").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Columns("M:M").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("M1").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ALL WORDS"
Range("N1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "COUNT"
Range("N2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"
Range("M3").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("N1048576").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Selection.FillDown
Range("N1048575").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Columns("M:N").Select
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "temp!R1C13:R1048576C14",      Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="temp!R1C16:R1C17", TableName:="PivotTable2", _
    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
Sheets("temp").Select
Cells(1, 16).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("ALL WORDS")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable2").PivotFields("COUNT"), "Sum of COUNT", xlSum
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlToRight).Select
Columns("P:Q").Select
Selection.Copy
Columns("S:T").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Range("S2:T2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlToLeft).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Range("J3").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("J113487:K113487").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Range("J226972:K226972").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.ClearContents
Range("J226970").Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Range("J1:K1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Range("J2").Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
Range("J226971:K226971").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "temp!R1C10:R226971C11", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="temp!R1C22:R1C23", TableName:="PivotTable3", _
    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
Sheets("temp").Select
Cells(1, 22).Select
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Row Labels")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable3").PivotFields("Sum of COUNT"), "Sum of Sum of COUNT", xlSum
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 10
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 11
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 12
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 13
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 14
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 15
ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 16
Range("W2").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Row Labels").AutoSort _
    xlDescending, "Sum of Sum of COUNT", ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3"). _
    PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(1), 1
Range("V1:W1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range("V1:W1048573").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
ActiveSheet.Paste

End If

 End Sub
```

Comment: hard to tell without seeing the macro code...

Comment: no need to shout (as upper case would mean). and now: what line does throw that error? BTW: there are a lot of `Select`/`Activate` which is not best practice and may arise issues: change them with direct and fully qualified range references (search SO for this and you'll get details

Comment: Concerning that half of the code is coming from a macro recorder, it would be time consuming to track down the error. Probably you want to rewrite it and ask once again?

Answer (score 0):

what follows is a quite far from perfect refactoring of your code, but it should help you getting in the right direction to avoid the `Activate`/`Select` pattern

a final part of your code is commented since it'd not run as there most probably lack some code before

step through it and see what revisions are needed

good coding

```
Option Explicit

Sub MakeWordList()
    Dim answer As VbMsgBoxResult

    answer = MsgBox("ARE YOU SURE YOU WANT TO RUN THIS WORD COUNT MACRO...? ", vbYesNo, "RUN WORD COUNT")
    If answer = vbYes Then

        Dim InputSheet As Worksheet, WordListSheet As Worksheet
'        Dim Result As Worksheet '<-- not used
        Dim PuncChars As Variant, x As Variant
        Dim i As Long, r As Long, lastrow As Long
        Dim txt As String
        Dim wordCnt As Long
'        Dim AllWords As Range'<-- not used
'        Dim pc As PivotCache '<-- not used
'        Dim pt As PivotTable '<-- not used
        Dim OutClm As Long

'        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set InputSheet = ActiveSheet

        Set WordListSheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Sheets.Count))
        With WordListSheet
            .name = "temp"
            With .Range("A1:B1")
                .Value = "All Words"
                .Font.Bold = True
            End With
        End With

        wordCnt = 2
        PuncChars = Array(".", ",", ";", ":", "'", "!", "#", "-", "--", "---", "@", "`", _
        "$", "%", "&", "(", ")", " - ", "_", "--", "+", "<", ">", "BLANK", _
        "=", "~", "/", "\", "{", "}", "[", "]", """", "?", "*", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
        r = 1
        OutClm = 1
        With InputSheet
        '   Loop until blank cell is encountered
            Do While .Cells(r, 1) <> ""
                '       covert to UPPERCASE
                txt = UCase(.Cells(r, 1))
                '       Remove punctuation
                For i = 0 To UBound(PuncChars)
                     txt = Replace(txt, PuncChars(i), "")
                Next i
                '       Remove excess spaces
                txt = WorksheetFunction.Trim(txt)
                '       Extract the words
                x = Split(txt)

                For i = 0 To UBound(x)
                    If wordCnt > WordListSheet.Rows.Count Then
                        OutClm = OutClm + 1
                        wordCnt = 1
                    End If
                    WordListSheet.Cells(wordCnt, OutClm) = x(i)
                    wordCnt = wordCnt + 1
                Next i
                r = r + 1
            Loop
        End With
        '
        ' Macro1 Macro
        With WordListSheet
            .Columns("A:A").Copy
            .Columns("D:D").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            .Range("E1").FormulaR1C1 = "COUNT"
            .Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "1"
            .Range(.Range("E1048576"), .Range("E1048576").End(xlUp)).FillDown
            .Columns("D:E").Select
            ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                              SourceData:="temp!R1C4:R1048576C5", _
                                              Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15) _
                                      .CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="temp!R1C7:R1C8", _
                                                        TableName:="PivotTable1", _
                                                        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15

            .Cells(1, 7).Select
            With .PivotTables("PivotTable1")
                With .PivotFields("All Words")
                    .Orientation = xlRowField
                    .Position = 1
                End With
                .AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
            "PivotTable1").PivotFields("COUNT"), "Sum of COUNT", xlSum
            End With

            .Columns("G:H").Copy
            .Columns("J:K").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            .Columns("B:B").Copy
            .Columns("M:M").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            .Range("M1").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "ALL WORDS"
            .Range("N1").FormulaR1C1 = "COUNT"
            .Range("N2").FormulaR1C1 = "1"
            .Range(.Range("N1048576"), .Range("N1048576").End(xlUp)).FillDown
            .Columns("M:N").Select
            ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                              SourceData:="temp!R1C13:R1048576C14", _
                                              Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15) _
                                      .CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="temp!R1C16:R1C17", _
                                                        TableName:="PivotTable2", _
                                                        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15

            .Cells(1, 16).Select
            With .PivotTables("PivotTable2")
                With .PivotFields("ALL WORDS")
                    .Orientation = xlRowField
                    .Position = 1
                End With
                .AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
            "PivotTable2").PivotFields("COUNT"), "Sum of COUNT", xlSum
            End With

            .Columns("P:Q").Copy
            .Columns("S:T").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            .Range(.Range("S2:T2"), .Range("S2:T2").End(xlDown)).Copy
            .Range("J113487:K113487").Select
            .Paste
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            .Range("J226972:K226972").ClearContents
            .Range(.Range("J226971:K226971"), .Range("J226971:K226971").End(xlUp)).Select
            ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                                              SourceData:="temp!R1C10:R226971C11", _
                                              Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15) _
                                      .CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="temp!R1C22:R1C23", _
                                                        TableName:="PivotTable3", _
                                                        DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion15
            .Cells(1, 22).Select
'            With .PivotTables("PivotTable3")
'                With .PivotFields("Row Labels") '<-- where has this field been defined?
'                .Orientation = xlRowField
'                .Position = 1
'                End With
'                .AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
'                "PivotTable3").PivotFields("Sum of COUNT"), "Sum of Sum of COUNT", xlSum
'            End With
'            .Range("W2").Select
'            .PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Row Labels").AutoSort _
'                                                                xlDescending, _
'                                                                "Sum of Sum of COUNT", _
'                                                                ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotColumnAxis.PivotLines(1), _
'                                                                1
'
'            .Range(.Range("V1:W1048573"), .Range("V1:W1048573").End(xlUp)).Copy
        End With
'        Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
'        ActiveSheet.Paste

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: this code is adding a sheet with name "temp" in exactly the same way your original code did. Maybe it's already there and this will raise an issue... Look, I think you have to: go step by step beginning with a reduced part of the code and validate it until it runs in all "posisble" conditions. Then Add new bits of code and do the same. If you get stuck at any step you'll have a much more consolidated and circumscribed piece of code to come to SO with and exactly address the _only_ current issue of. This is also an effective way to learn

Answer (score 0):

I think you should debug youe code line by line with f8... i believe there is a lot of code that can be removed: select range after selecting another range is almost always not needed and you can remove the previos selections. do copy and paste with one line...  select is a bad practice. check your pivot...  it looks like you are trying to add the same total field again and again. remove the scrolling lines.

dont use
range("E2").Select ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "1"

write
range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "1"
or
range("E2").value = "1"

Comment: its possible that you already have a sheet with the same name.  do you?